# Random no but unique from given no

Tags: php, mysql

Want to $ar array must be shuffle for every element of $arr, $query result have $row equal to elements of $ar

```
    $arr =["11","12"];
    $t_length= count($arr);
    for($i=0; $i < $t_length; $i++)
    {
         $ar=["1","2","3","4","5"];
         foreach ($query->result() as $row)
         {
              $data= array("stdid"=>$arr[$i],"tid"=>1);
                // tid for 11 may be some thing like
                // $ar=["1","2","3","4","5"]; and for next item  which 
                //12 may be $ar=["5","4","1","2","3"]; 
           }
       }
```

Comment: your array definitions are incorrect. use this syntax instead: `$ar = ['11','12']`

Comment: Sir it is an example

Comment: Well example or not, avoid programming mistakes and edit your question when one is pointed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$row` and `$ar` have an equal element count, I don't see the reason for two loops.  Your original code will do four iterations, and I'm not sure that's what you want.  (Judging by my uncertainty and the number of negative votes, you should probably update your question asap.)

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2343900add4181ead2b7cc0486af084c4f6d714d))

```
$arr=['11','12'];
$ar=['1','2','3','4','5'];

// shuffle and index $data subarrays
foreach($arr as $v){
    shuffle($ar); // just shuffle before the next loop
    $data[]=['stdid'=>$v,"tid"=>$ar];
}
var_export($data);

$data=[];  // clear the array
echo "\n\n---\n\n";

// or shuffle and use stdid as subarray keys for $data
foreach($arr as $v){
    shuffle($ar); // just shuffle before the next loop
    $data[$v]=["tid"=>$ar];
}
var_export($data);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'stdid' => '11',
    'tid' => 
    array (
      0 => '1',
      1 => '4',
      2 => '5',
      3 => '2',
      4 => '3',
    ),
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'stdid' => '12',
    'tid' => 
    array (
      0 => '4',
      1 => '5',
      2 => '2',
      3 => '3',
      4 => '1',
    ),
  ),
)

---

array (
  11 => 
  array (
    'tid' => 
    array (
      0 => '5',
      1 => '2',
      2 => '1',
      3 => '3',
      4 => '4',
    ),
  ),
  12 => 
  array (
    'tid' => 
    array (
      0 => '2',
      1 => '4',
      2 => '1',
      3 => '3',
      4 => '5',
    ),
  ),
)
```